# Discord.py how do i limit the amount of roles to 1 so that when i type command again it won't duplicate Muted role?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Role being limited to 1 is due to this being a Mute command, please help if possible.

```
        try:
            guild = ctx.guild
            await guild.create_role(name="Muted", limit=1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            await ctx.send("something went wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if the role exists.

```
    try:
        guild = ctx.guild
        if not guild.has_role(name="Muted"):
            await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send("something went wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the roles and check if the role already exists.

```py
try:
   guild = ctx.guild
   roles = guild.roles
   if 'Muted' in [role.name for role in roles]:
      await ctx.send("role already exists")
   else:
      await guild.create_role(name="Muted", limit=1)
```

`guild.roles` is a list of all the roles in the guild, you can also use `await guild.fetch_roles()` which is an API call that gets the same.

References:

- [fetch_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_roles)
- [role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.name)
- [roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)